# Strongly convex function evaluated over a mean of n points

Tags: convex, inequality

Let f(x) be a Strongly-convex function under some m > 0.

Given two points x, y it is known that:

$$f(\frac{x + y}{2}) \leq \frac{f(x) + f(y)}{2} - \frac{1}{2^3} \cdot m \cdot ||x - y||^2$$

What is the exact formulation when looking at the mean of n points.

$$f( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i) \leq \ \  ?$$

Comment: Whatever be $m>0$ this inequality is not true for a linear function which is convex, hence it will not hold either for a strictly convex function which is very close to a linear function.

Comment: Thanks you @Yves. I was mistaken and meant strongly-convex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard definition of strong convexity with a constant $m>0$ would read as follows: for $t \in [0,1]$,
                  $$ f(tx+(1-t)y) \leq t f(x) + (1-t) f(y) - mt(1-t) \left \| x-y  \right \|^2.$$
Now, there is a famous theorem that says that a function $f$ is strongly convex with constant $m>0$ if and only if the function $$g(x)=f(x)-m\left \| x \right \|^2$$ is convex.

By Jensen's inequality for convex functions, $$ g\Bigg(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i }{n} \Bigg)  \leq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} g(x_i).$$ Equivalently, 
$$ f\Bigg(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i }{n} \Bigg)   \leq m \left \| \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i }{n} \right \|^2 + \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \Big(f(x_i)- m \left \| x_i\right \|^2\Big) \\ \leq \frac{m(1-n)}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left \| x_i\right \|^2 + \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i),$$ 
where the last step follows from the triangle inequality.

See for example

> Nikodem, K. and Pales, Z., (2011). Characterizations of inner product spaces by strongly convex functions, Banach Journal of Mathematical Analysis, 5.1, 83-87.

for reference.

Comment: Seems that $\|x_i\|^2$ has to be replaced by $m \|x_i\|^2$ in the inequality.

Comment: @Yves Well spotted. Thank you!

Comment: By further using  $\|\sum x_i\|^2 \leq \sum \|x_i\|^2$ you can get a simpler inequality that can be useful.

Comment: Of course. I usually prefer to establish the strongest form of an inequality (given a set of arguments) and leave the consequences to the user's discretion.